# Where did Test List go in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Premium and was having a good time playing with it and writing unit tests (using MS unit tests).  However, the "Test Lists" window and some other Test related windows suddenly disappeared AND they have disappeared from the menu item 
Test->Windows.  In fact I remember Test->Windows having 4 items under it and now I only see two: Test Explorer, Code Coverage Results.  i stress they WERE present in Visual Studio 2013. Clearly, I hit some key combination that made them disappear or something happened to make them disappear.  **How do I get Test List back?**  Please don't see they are under Tests->Windows, because for me, they are not (at least now.  they were!)

Anyone else seen this?  Any solutions?  I tried restarting Visual Studio, rebooting.

Also, previously, under the "Test" menu, there was a Debug->"Test in Context" and a Run->"Test in Context", or something like this.  It was very handy.  If your cursor was with in some test, you could run just that one.  I'm guessing this is related.

Comment: Did you switch projects?

Comment: Andrew, no I didn't switch projects.  I did pull in a solution from Visual Studio 2010.  I'm wondering if somehow the options/choices were obliterated because they were there in 2013 for a couple of hours.  Since posting, I have been using "Playlist" which seems to do most of what "Test Lists" did.

Comment: Test lists is a 2010 feature, and playlist is a 2013 feature. Not really sure how you were using them in 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all I know, these features have been "optimized" into the new test-window... a.k.a. they have been removed. Some other unit test related features are also gone (the context menu item for "create unit tests" is gone for example, yet can still be called via the command window)

Personally I think this is Microsoft's way of pushing everybody towards the Team Foundation Server but that's just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment Roman.  I guess I didn't make my question clear (I will edit it).  The menu items were present in Visual Studio 2013, and then just disappeared.  Possibly, I inadvertently made them disappear, or something happened to them.

Comment: @AndrewClear I don't use TFS myself but from what I know about it, the "Team Explorer" features might provide what's missing from the standalone version. But since I'm a "one man team", I don't really need any of the typical TFS features.

Comment: @Dave I'll check my installation. All I remember is that they never showed up in mine and all research pointed to them disappearing...

Comment: Unit tests have nothing to do with Team Explorer or TFS.

Comment: @AndrewClear unit tests are integrated in automated build processes though. And the product line that contains testing seems to be going towards "ALM" where the first part is "setup TFS" -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fda2bad5.aspx  - like I said: that's how it looks to me... I have no insight into the dev-team at MS.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. In my case I needed to install the NUnit plugin ("Nunit test adapter"). After restarting the tests came back.

Answer (score -1):

Start **Developer Command Prompt**:

- cd to UnitTest-folder\bin\Debug which contains .dll
- enter command: mstest /testcontainer:UnitTestMyTest.dll
  (this creates the test-result)

in **VS**:

- menu View / Other Windows / Test Results
- manage Test Runs: window Test Runs -> connect to Test Run
- browse to test-folder\bin\Debug\TestResults

Comment: did you really try it out?! :-P